# Apply lambda function to two columns in two Pandas dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, string, fuzzy-comparison

I have two data frames that I'm trying to merge, based on a primary & foreign key of company name. One data set has ~50,000 unique company names, the other one has about 5,000. Duplicate company names are possible within each list. I'm trying to produce some string-edit distance metrics comparing two columns between two data frames.

Here's an MWE with example data frames:

```
mwe1 = pd.DataFrame({'company_name': ['Deloitte', 
                                      'PriceWaterhouseCoopers', 
                                      'KPMG',
                                      'Ernst & Young',
                                      'intentionall typo company XYZ'
                                     ],
                    'revenue': [100, 200, 300, 250, 400]
                   }
                  )

mwe2 = pd.DataFrame({'salesforce_name': ['Deloite',
                                         'PriceWaterhouseCooper'
                                        ],
                     'CEO': ['John', 'Jane']
                    }
                   )
```

I want:

```
company_name                   revenue    salesforce_name         CEO     similarity_score ...
Deloitte                       100        Deloite                 John    98
PriceWaterhouseCoopers         200        Deloite                 John    0
KPMG                           300        Deloite                 John    15
Ernst & Young                  250        Deloite                 John    10
intentionall typo company XYZ  400        Deloite                 John    2
Deloitte                       100        PriceWaterhouseCooper   Jane    20
PriceWaterhouseCoopers         200        PriceWaterhouseCooper   Jane    97
KPMG                           300        PriceWaterhouseCooper   Jane    5
Ernst & Young                  250        PriceWaterhouseCooper   Jane    7
intentionall typo company XYZ  400        PriceWaterhouseCooper   Jane    3
```

In the above, there's 1 similarity score. In actuality, I'd like to have several columns, one for each metric. Example metrics include Jaro-Winkler, Levenshtein, etc. Here's an example I found producing the metric for two strings, but how do I use this for two Pandas Series of unequal length, like my MWE example?

```
import abydos.distance as abd
abd.DiscountedLevenshtein().sim('coca-cola company','coca-cola group')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a common column for both datasets and then we can use pandas merge on that common column

Here is the sample code

```
mwe1['common']=mwe2['common']=1
df = pd.merge(mwe1,mwe2,on='common').drop('common',1)
df.sort_values(by='salesforce_name',inplace=True)
```

Output:

```
                    company_name  revenue        salesforce_name   CEO
0                       Deloitte      100                Deloite  John
2         PriceWaterhouseCoopers      200                Deloite  John
4                           KPMG      300                Deloite  John
6                  Ernst & Young      250                Deloite  John
8  intentionall typo company XYZ      400                Deloite  John
1                       Deloitte      100  PriceWaterhouseCooper  Jane
3         PriceWaterhouseCoopers      200  PriceWaterhouseCooper  Jane
5                           KPMG      300  PriceWaterhouseCooper  Jane
7                  Ernst & Young      250  PriceWaterhouseCooper  Jane
9  intentionall typo company XYZ      400  PriceWaterhouseCooper  Jane
```